# shell script for loop printing file names complete path

Tags: shell

Im using below shell scripts,

```
    INBOX=/home/tmp/
    for fileName in $INBOX"abc*.csv"
    do
        echo $fileName
    done

    **output:**
       /home/tmp/abc1.csv
       /home/tmp/abc2.csv
    
    **Expected output:**
    abc1.csv
    abc2.csv
```

it is printing files with whole path. But I need only file name alone.

Thanks

Comment: To get your output `echo "${filename##*/}"` (which is *Parameter Expansion with substring removal* that trims all characters from the front of the string through the last `'/'`)

Comment: Additionally, the `'*'` should be outside of double quotes for pathname expansion to occur resulting in individual filenames to process. When within double quotes, the filenames will be part of a single string separated by the first character of `IFS`. Better `"$INBOX"abc*.csv`

Comment: While this link  I posted as duplicate for your question, discusses the problem for _bash_, the solution also work in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INBOX=/home/tmp/
for fileName in $INBOX"abc*.csv"
do
     echo $(basename $fileName)
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two primary problems preventing the output you want:

1. You have enclosed the `'*'` within double-quotes which will result in all your filenames being part of a single string separated by the first character of your internal field separator;
2. You need to trim the leading `/home/tmp/` from the resulting filename which you can do with *Parameter Expansion with Substring Removal* of the form `${filename##*/}`. (which will trim characters from the front of `filename` through the last included `'/'`)

You can put that together in your script as:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

INBOX=/home/tmp/
for fileName in "$INBOX"abc*.csv
do
    echo "${fileName##*/}"
done
```